# keyboard.hook_key() stops responding to presses after some kind of error. Only after compiling to .exe

Tags: python, keyboard, pyautogui, keyboard-hook

The problem only appears after compiling to .exe: in line `keyboard.hook_key ('f7', TranslateAll, suppress = True)` when pressing *F7* calls the function `TranslateAll`. Function algorithm:

1. Library `pyperclip` pulls text from the clipboard
2. Library `googletrans` translates text
3. `pyperclip` inserts the translated text into clipboard

Everything works fine, however, after compiling to .exe, after 10 function calls, `keyboard.hook_key()` stops responding.

I've tried reassigning *F7* in `keyboard.hook_key ()` on error, but that didn't work either.

**What could be the problem?**

**The problematic part of the code:** (You can try running it to see it work and then using pyinstaller "NameOfCode.py" to see the problem I described)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from googletrans import Translator
import keyboard
import googletrans
import pyperclip

count = 0                         #function operation counter

TranslateAll_count = 0            #variable, for single
                                  #triggering a function when a button is pressed

def TranslateAll(event):
    global TranslateAll_count
    global count
    TranslateAll_count += 1
    if TranslateAll_count != 2:

        #main algorithm 

        translator = Translator()

        data = pyperclip.paste()

        result = translator.translate(data, dest='ru')

        pyperclip.copy(result.text)

        TranslateAll_count = 1
        count += 1
        print(f'Actuation №{count}\n')


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):

        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setFixedSize(QSize(480, 180))
        self.setWindowTitle("test")

        #binding F7 to a function TranslateAll
        keyboard.hook_key('f7', TranslateAll, suppress=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**Output when running a .py file:**

```
Actuation №1
Actuation №2
Actuation №3
Actuation №4
#until the user finishes work
```

**Output when running .exe file:**

```
#7 Actuations
Actuation №8
#the function stops being called
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the function call line `keyboard.hook_key('f7', TranslateAll, suppress=True)`

To get rid of the problem, it was only necessary to change the value of the `suppress` parameter from `True` to `False`